# Add extra latency on top of existing tc qdiscs

Tags: linux, tc, latency, traffic-shaping

On a system with an existing multi-stage qdisc setup, we need to introduce extra latency (at least fixed, but fixed with a small variation would be a nice option to have).

The canonical way to do this on Linux is to use the `netem` qdisc. However, this cannot work here because `netem` does not work with other qdiscs (this is a [well-documented](https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/codel/wiki/Best_practices_for_benchmarking_Codel_and_FQ_Codel/#the-netem-qdisc-does-not-work-in-conjunction-with-other-qdiscs) limitation, and one which a coworker has verified himself).

Putting a VM onto the machine that does nothing but `netem` not only seems like overkill but will also massively complicate routing and WLAN configuration so that’s a step I would prefer not to take.

In case it’s relevant, the current setup is a combination of `htb` (used to limit bandwidth only… we probably should have used `tbf` instead but this is what we had when I joined) and `fq_codel` for ECN marking, both with custom patches. I’m not averse to patching this into either…

As requested, here is a sample setup, using stock `htb`/`fq_codel` for easier testing:

```
#!/bin/mksh
set -ex
dev=eth0
rate=1000
sudo tc qdisc add dev $dev root handle 1: htb default 1
sudo tc class add dev $dev parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate ${rate}kbit ceil ${rate}kbit prio 1
sudo tc qdisc add dev $dev parent 1:1 handle 2: fq_codel
```

Comment: Could you point to the well-documented limitation that netem does not work with other qdiscs? Also if you could show some of your "code" (ie: the tc hierarchy or commands), it would be easier to validate if an idea is working or not.

Comment: @A.B added inline (link, but a coworker has seen that problem himself; sample setup code modified to use stock qdisc modules so you can test things easier)